# Jquery Validation only when one field is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm working on what I think is a tricky jquery validation situation.

I have a situation in which I need will need an error thrown only if one field is blank.

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-3'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="arrivalDate">Assignment Start</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="arrivalDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" name="arrivalDate" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-3'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="assignmentEnd">Assignment End</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assignmentEnd" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" name="assignmentEnd" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So, what I would like to happen is:

If there is text in the assignmentEnd field, the arrivalDate field can't be blank. It should throw an error message.

I have tried to write a validator but I don't think I have it right:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("contractCheck",   function(value,element,params) {
        if ((value).val().length != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    "Field can't be blank"
);
```

Calling in in the code:

```
      assignmentEnd: {
        contractCheck: "#arrivalDate"
      },  


   assignmentEnd: {
        required: "This can not be blank."
      },
```

*Note I don't have it like this, I just wanted to include how I'm calling it. It's int he proper format to be called and evaluated like other fields.

When I do try to run this code it actually throws and error but submits the form (which should not happen) so I can't look up the error message.

Comment: Is this what you want? `if ($('#assignmentEnd').val().length != 0 && $('#arrivalDate').val().length == 0)`

Comment: @sam  Quick ? Did should that code go in the $.validator.addMethod portion of the code or should it be run like regular Javascript? I did put it into it's own validator but it didn't fire. It also didn't trip an error message.

Comment: I tend to do manual validation most of the time, so I'm not much help with validator, but if you put an event on your form submit, and use `preventdefault()` this code may become more useful to you.

Comment: @sam Thanks. I think this will work for manual val but I was trying to keep it in the jquery validator. However, this is an option to use if I can't get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Please be mindful with your tags... jQuery Validation Engine has nothing to do with this.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a situation in which I need will need an error thrown only if one field is blank.

You don't need to write a custom rule or do anything other than declaring the `required` rule on the second field using a *dependency* function.

```
$('#yourform').validate({
    rules: {
        assignmentEnd: {
            required: function(element) { 
                // required ONLY when other field is NOT blank
                return $('#arrivalDate').is(':filled');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/nwfyngwq/](http://jsfiddle.net/nwfyngwq/)

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try to work this in.. This page is extremely complicated and I can see how this will work.  Since there are so many other things going on I have to be very careful to insert this and not break anything else. I believe this is the solution that I need but I have to be very careful about using it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Update: This is working for me. Thanks a lot. Full disclosure, I was working on this in two different work environments and when I went home I had the wrong env open.. This solution worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input` event to check if `#assignmentEnd` element `.value` is valid, if true set `required` attribute for both `#arrivalDate` and `#assignmentEnd` elements, else remove `required` attribute with `.attr()`, `.removeAttr()`

```js
$("#assignmentEnd").on("input", function() {
  if (this.value.length && this.checkValidity()) {
    $(this).add("#arrivalDate").attr("required", "required")
  } else {
    $(this).add("#arrivalDate").removeAttr("required")
  }
})
```

```css
:invalid + label:after {
  content: "Field cannot be blank";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="arrivalDate">Assignment Start</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="arrivalDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" name="arrivalDate" pattern="^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$"/>
        <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="assignmentEnd">Assignment End</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assignmentEnd" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" name="assignmentEnd" pattern="^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$"/>
        <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the tricky part of these fields are that are NOT required. If data is submitted, it should a) be a valid date field, b) then fire this logic. I am adding in those requirements when some custom javascript but its not always required that these fields get filled in.

Comment: What do you mean by _"If there is text in the assignmentEnd field, the arrivalDate field can't be blank"_?

Comment: He means if you give an end date, you have to give an arrival date also. Otherwise, neither are required.

Comment: @weggie Does logic at updated stacksnippets return expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying it out now. Will get right back to you.

Comment: @guest271314 So, this is odd. When I tried to trip this, I get an error that says "Invalid Format" And its under Assignment End. Weird? So like any time I put in what should be a valid date I get Invalid Format.

Comment: Included `pattern` attribute at `input` elements with `RegExp` `\d+|/`, will adjust

Comment: I have pattern and the regex stuff in place.. but to confirm, you wanted the :invalid stuff in <script></script> tags correct?

Comment: See updated post. `:invalid` is a `css` selector at `.css` file or `<style>` element

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks I seem to have it working but it is not yielding the intended result. I'll take what I learned here and try to mold it into a solution that will work for me. Thanks for your help!